# sort by and then in c++ using lambda functions

Tags: c++, lambda

In C# given a struct:

```
struct Point {int x, int y}
```

We can write something like:

```
List<Point> list;
list.OrderBy(p => p.x).ThenBy(q => q.y);
```

How can I express this logic in C++ using lambda functions?

Comment: So you want  to sort by `x` and then by `y`?

Comment: @GauravSehgal Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks too me like you want a lexicographic sort on `(y, x)`<sup>1</sup>. You can leverage the library function [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie). That one returns a tuple of references, and a `std::tuple` has a less-than operator which performs lexicographic comparison. So you only need to specify the order in which you want the items compared.

Here's how it would look for `std::vector` (your go to container type in C++, always start with `std::vector`):

```
std::vector<Point> my_list;
// Fill my_list
std::sort(begin(my_list), end(my_list), [](auto const& l, auto const& r){
  return std::tie(l.y, l.x) < std::tie(r.y, r.x);
});
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - I'm basing this on the method names only, so this may *not* be what you are really after.</sub>

Comment: Python lists are more similar to C++ vectors than linked lists.

Comment: @n.m.- What about C# lists? The OP asked based on that. I'm not familiar with C# too well myself.

Comment: According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943229/c-sharp-equivalent-of-c-vector-with-contiguous-memory), apparently the same...

Comment: @Aconcagua - Amended answer accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: My bad, assumed Python wrongly but apparently C# lists are also more like vectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use STL function std::sort. Example:

```
struct point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

// Compare function. This can be lambda function too.
bool comp(const point& a,const point& b){ 
    if(a.x > b.x) return true;
    else if(a.x == b.x) return a.y > b.y;
    return false;
}


int main(){    
    // v is vector (or any other container which can be iterated) containing points
    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),comp);
}
```

Comment: You just sorted by x in this way.
You should add `If(a.x==b.x) return a.y>b.y;` i guess.

Comment: Yes. I just wrote some dummy compare function. But I will add the code as per your suggestion for clarity.

Comment: `((a.x > b.x) and (a.y > b.y))` is a wrong and dangerous comparison, not suitable for sorting.

Comment: @n.m. It would be great if you can explain me a bit on when can it go wrong.

Comment: Consider the case where `a.x > b.x`, but `a.y < b.y`. Your function will return false for both `comp(a, b)` and `comp(b, a)`, which indicates that `a` and `b`  should be considered equal. But they clearly should not.

Comment: Thanks!. I changed it.

Comment: Just a slight remark for performance: as equality is probably the least frequent case you could put it last in the if/else suite for a slightly more efficient comparison, and use ternary operator which is very readable for simple expressions like these (this is just a suggestion, I like if/else). So that would be `return (a.x < b.x) ? true : (a.x > b.x) ? false : (a.y > b.y);`

Answer (score 1):

Two ways - either you sort twice, first by y, then use a *stable* sort on x (be aware that this is exactly inverse as in C#!). Bad luck with `std::sort`, though, as it is not stable, fortunately, as Benjamin hinted to, there is `std::stable_sort`, too...

The other way is making sure that two points compare such that a difference in x applies first and only in case of equality, y is considered:

```
std::sort
(
    // range to sort
    list.begin(), list.end(),
    // next the comparator - you wanted a lambda? OK, here it is:
    [](point const& a, point const& b)
    {
        return a.x < b.x || a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y;
    }
);
```

Comment: `std::sort` may not be stable, but there is another function in the standard library that is. Curiously named `std::stable_sort`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks for the hint. Didn't cope much for the first approach as I consider the second one superior anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the lambda function to `std::list::sort()`.You decide how you want to sort.

```
list.sort([](Point  i,Point  j)
            {
               if(i.x!=j.x)
                   return i.x<j.x;
               else
                   return i.y<j.y;
             }
          );
```

Comment: You'd better use `const Point &`

Comment: @user2807083 Actually no, in this case Point is sizeof == 8 on x64 systems, so copying it is better than using a reference